# Entity getting saved without @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

We are facing a some issue related to spring `@Transactional`, we have a controller and a service class, though the service class is not marked with `@Transactional`, entity is getting saved. We are using `@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)` and `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` also **spring data JPA**. I guess this info may not be sufficient but any insight on what could be the possible reasons for this behavior. Few logs before entity persistence

```
2016-01-07 20:58:15,393 DEBUG [org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] (default task-23)  Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-01-07 20:58:15,393 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (default task-23)  Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2016-01-07 20:58:15,394 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl] (default task-23)  Skipping JTA sync registration due to auto join checking
2016-01-07 20:58:15,394 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl] (default task-23)  Skipping JTA sync registration due to auto join checking
2016-01-07 20:58:15,394 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl] (default task-23)  successfully registered Synchronization
2016-01-07 20:58:15,394 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl] (default task-23)  Looking for a JTA transaction to join
2016-01-07 20:58:15,394 DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler] (default task-23)  Joined JTA transaction
2016-01-07 20:58:15,394 DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (default task-23)  Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'jpaAuditingHandler'
2016-01-07 20:58:15,417 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (smsQueueListenerBean-1)   Initiating transaction commit
2016-01-07 20:58:15,417 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (smsQueueListenerBean-1)   Creating new transaction with name [smsQueueListenerBean]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2016-01-07 20:58:15,418 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (emailQueueListenerBean-1)   Initiating transaction commit
2016-01-07 20:58:15,418 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (emailQueueListenerBean-1)   Creating new transaction with name [emailQueueListenerBean]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2016-01-07 20:58:15,459 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (default task-23)  Participating in existing transaction
2016-01-07 20:58:15,459 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (default task-23)  Participating in existing transaction
2016-01-07 20:58:15,460 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (default task-23)  Obtaining JDBC connection
2016-01-07 20:58:15,461 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (default task-23)  Obtained JDBC connection
2016-01-07 20:58:15,463 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl] (default task-23)  Starting ResultSet row #0
2016-01-07 20:58:15,463 DEBUG [org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl] (default task-23)  On call to EntityIdentifierReaderImpl#resolve, EntityKey was already known; should only happen on root returns with an optional identifier specified
2016-01-07 20:58:15,464 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (default task-23)  Releasing JDBC connection
2016-01-07 20:58:15,465 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] (default task-23)  Released JDBC connection
```

Comment: Could you put some class code, JavaConfig, ...?

Comment: This is because, as you said, you're using `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` that opens transaction before executing code in controller. Or it's not?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have method with @Transactional annotation earlier in call stack?

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA there is nothing much in code apart from i have explained above, i'm not using Transactional annotation neither in my Controller nor in my Service classes, Java Config is just like in the spring transaction management sample project.

Comment: @slava-semushin OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor doesn't open transactions, it only binds the entitymanager to the current thread.

Comment: @Nick when you seek help, at least help us to help by giving us the needed code that we can understand the whole situation. If you can't do this, then we can't do much for you. Good luck

Comment: @SlavaSemushin I'm afraid [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.java#OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor) is opening transaction

Comment: I don't see any code in your link, that is opening a transaction. Can you point to the line, where you see that?

Comment: @KenBekov There is no Transactional annotation is used in this Specific Controller or Service callstack but there are other services injected into this Controller which is having Transactional annotation

Comment: Could you also elaborate, what your expected behaviour would be? Also, as you can see in the second line of your logfile, the transaction is started by the EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl, which comes from Spring Data. By default, the repository methods in Spring Data are transactional.

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA I'm sorry about it, i guess the description is self explanatory . If you insist i can just add one controller and server pseudo code here without Transactional annotation

Comment: @dunni as far as my understanding on Spring Transaction management when we annotate a method or class with Transactional then only spring will do a transaction management, and i'm not sure on spring data jpa will add transaction scope either, Please correct me if i'm wrong. I will edit and add transaction opening log if i can find it in my log.

Comment: Look at this : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java. this explains that, because of using spring data your repositories are transactionaware. Thus, the transaction been started for you. You can see the @transactional at the beginning of the class

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA thanks for pointing it out but I'm not extending my repository from SimpleJpaRepository but extending from [JpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.java)

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA can you please tell me does spring data jpa internally uses SimpleJpaRepository or similar to mark calls as transactional ?

Comment: Of course, SimpleJpaRepository works as the template implementation for all repository interfaces which are extended from JpaRepository.

Comment: @dunni no i was asking, does spring data jpa creates transaction even if the service is not marked with Transactional ?

Comment: Well, we already gave you the answer: Yes it does, because SimpleJpaRepository is annotated with `@Transactional` and Spring Data JPA uses this class as implementation for all repository interfaces, which are extended from JpaRepository.

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA and dunni thanks guys for clarifying it for me, i was totally unaware and was in an impression that, we are responsible to add transactional scope by adding Transactional annotation. Thanks...

Comment: SimpleJpaRepository is the default implementation of JpaRepository. To be convinced, you can debug with a breakpoint in this class. You can see it by yourself.
You're welcome :)

Comment: @ZakariaeMAHLA I understood and i read a bit more in Transaction management side on spring data jpa... Thanks a lot...

Comment: @Nick This is a very good choice for getting the whole image. Good luck

Comment: Thanks @ZakariaeMAHLA, sometimes its good dive deep :-). Unfortunately i have no idea how to convert a stackoverflow comment as correct answer :D

Comment: I was editing an answer, so it can be a reference for someone who is facing the same problem. Thanks for the vote up :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up what we discussed in the comments:
[SimpleJpaRepository](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java) is the default implementation of JpaRepository interface. If we look at this implementation, we can see that, by default, we are using a read-only transaction (for methods like findAll, ...), and for deleting or saving services, they are annotated with @transactional. QEF.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment :-)